# Having a command line argument in a backticked AWK expression

Tags: bash

I have a script where I run a pipeline and the last command is `awk`, and I'd like to place a command line argument in that part.

```
OUTPUT=`sort -t' ' -k +6,6 -k +7,7 | awk '{print "        $1"$0}'`
```

I'd like the `$1` in the end to be the argument that I received when I ran the script, instead of being treated as a dollar-one string and being parsed by the `awk` command.

Is there an elegant solution for that, or should I just pass on the `awk` part and then iterate over every line of  `OUTPUT` and add the spaces and arguments I wanted to add with `awk`?

Comment: It's a good idea to get into the habit of using `$(command)` instead of backticks, btw. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082 and https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2006 for details.

Comment: @Shawn Didn't even know that's possible. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-v`.

```
$: set -- foo # set $1 for this example
$: awk -v arg1=$1 '{print "        ", arg1, $0}' < someInput
```

Or without the spaces (more like you had),

```
$: awk -v arg1=$1 '{print "        " arg1 $0}' < someInput
```

c.f. the (in this case GNU) [`awk` user manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Invoking-Gawk)

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution is to use the "unquote requote" trick to move the `$1` outside of the single quotes:

```
OUTPUT=`sort -t' ' -k +6,6 -k +7,7 | awk '{print "        '$1'"$0}'`
```

You're also probably going to want to unset `IFS` **before** that command in your script to prevent "Word Splitting", if you're not already doing it. Otherwise `bash` is going to "edit out" all extra whitespace, including the newlines:

```
IFS=
OUTPUT=`sort -t' ' -k +6,6 -k +7,7 | awk '{print "        '$1'"$0}'`
```

Comment: This is fragile, as it depends on `$1` not containing any characters that will change how the `awk` script is parsed.

Comment: @chepner It's still inside double quotes within awk, so I don't think it's fragile to anything except an embedded double-quote, which I doubt is likely. But point taken.